# Laravel migration add colum issue in existing database table

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in laravel 4.2 project and now i want to add column in existing table users. Now i want to add another column and when i run migration command then I always receive the same message "Nothing to migrate."
Below is my migration modal code

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->string('dob')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

Commant that I run in terminal

```
 php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2017_08_29_130700_add_colum_user_is_black_list.php
```

I also run the following command

```
php artisan migrate
```

But when I run the above command then I receive following error

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR then I receive this error "SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists"

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the following steps for adding a column in existing table using laravel migrations.

**Laravel 3+, 4+**

1. Make a migration using CLI as (Use a specific name to avoid clashing with existing models)

   `php artisan migrate:make add_dob_users_table --table=users`

**Laravel 5+**

1. Make a migration using CLI as (Use a specific name to avoid clashing with existing models)

   `php artisan make:migration add_dob_to_users`

**Laravel 3+**

2. Use the `Schema::table()` method (As you're accessing an existing table, not creating a new one) and add a column like this:

   ```
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::table('users', function($table) {
           $table->string('dob')->nullable()->change();
       });
   }
   ```
3. Add the rollback option:

   ```
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::table('users', function($table) {
           $table->dropColumn('dob');
       });
   }
   ```

**Laravel 4+, 5+**

2. Use the `Schema::table()` method (As you're accessing an existing table, not creating a new one) and add a column like this:

   ```
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
           $table->string('dob')->nullable()->change();
       });
   }
   ```
3. Add the rollback option:

   ```
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
           $table->dropColumn('dob');
       });
   }
   ```

**Laravel 3+, 4+, 5+**

4. Finally run your migrations as

   `php artisan migrate`

Docs for creating and running migrations are

**Laravel 3+**

[Laravel 3 Schema Builder](https://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/database/schema)

[Laravel 3 Migrations](https://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/database/migrations)

**Laravel 4, 5**

[Laravel Schema Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema)

[Laravel Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations)

Comment: still facing same issue "[PDOException]                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists " even I follow the same steps that you defined.

Comment: what laravel version you are using?

Comment: try add a `bluprint` to the function as `Schema::table('users', function(User $table) { `

Comment: check the doc here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: Laravel 4.2 version I am using

Comment: @RizwanSaleem i have changed my answer according to your laravel version, please check again